# how to make a new data set from original dataset with data only from a specific date

Tags: r

I have an original dataset called `covid_cases` and I need to make a new dataset called `delta_cases` bases on the `covid_cases` dataset with data only from the date 17th of august 2021
I have tried :

```
delta_cases <- covid_cases %>%
  filter(Date > '2021-08-17')
```

but that gave me no data

Answer (score 0):

Your Date column must be a `Date` class , you can use `as.Date` function something like :

```
covid_cases$Date <- as.Date(covid_cases$Date)
```

then you can compare dates with

```
delta_cases <- covid_cases %>% filter(Date > '2021-08-17')
```

**Edit**

Here is simple data set to help

```r
library(dplyr , warn.conflicts = FALSE)

example <- data.frame(Date = c("2022-12-31" , "2022-12-30" ,"2022-12-29" , "2022-12-28")
                 , n_cases = c(12,23,12,34))
example$Date <- as.Date(example$Date)

delta_casses <- example %>% filter(Date > "2022-12-29")

delta_casses
#>         Date n_cases
#> 1 2022-12-31      12
#> 2 2022-12-30      23
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: it already is in date class, but is still not working

Comment: Would you check the class of covid_cases Date column with `class(covid_cases$Date)`

Answer (score 0):

If `str(covid_cases$Date)` is indeed a date class, `example %>% filter(Date > '2022-12-29')` should work. You may have additional packages that are interfering with `dplyr::filter()`. Try running the following code to clear all packages and reload `dplyr`

```
invisible(lapply(
  paste0('package:', names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)),
  detach,
  character.only = TRUE,
  unload = TRUE
))
library(dplyr)
```